# Execute commands in ipython shell from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ipython

i wrote a bash script that use different Linux terminal commands like ls and others, and then i have a command which will open interactive Python shell where the sign in terminal will be:

In [1]:

and i want my bash script to be able to continue and execute commands in that interactive Python shell.
i read a solution where we can execute bash script from within the interactive Python shell but i want the opposite, cause i want my bash script later to exit that interactive Python shell and continue with normal terminal commands..

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533156/using-python-in-a-bash-script

Comment: that's it! i was looking for that python -c command.. thank you! and i discovered that any command that opens ipython shell is the same as python command!